# Forcefully abort merge in progress in TFS/Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017

I was in the middle of a merge in TFS, but I want to abort my merge because there are a couple of things I need to fix in my files before I merge.

When I click on the Abort option though, nothing happens. I saw my cursor have a spinner icon for about 10 seconds, but that's about it--nothing else happened. Restarting Visual Studio didn't help either.

Is there any way I can force an abort on this merge?

Comment: Hi, is this a TFVC merge or a Git Merge?

Comment: Hi LOL. NO., any update, did you get a chance to implement the solution that I suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Comment: @Etienne It was a git merge, I believe.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT I'll update this with the workaround I had to do, but unstaging didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a GitKraken license, and ended up switching over to that to see if I could do things over there. Unfortunately GitKraken couldn't do much either, so we ended up deleting my local repository and checking it out again.

Since I think this was a git merge done thru VS, we probably could've done a git merge --abort--though I'm not sure if we would've run into this issue too. I've just never been too comfortable with the git CLI other than the very basic fetch/pull/push.

In the end, what I was working on was only a few files I created, all of which were < 20 lines and I just made quick backups of them. Not an ideal solution unfortunately...but it got the job done. :/

Comment: Thanks for the sharing, you could *mark your reply as an answer*, which will also help others in the community.